# update master page control in click on client page control how can do this

Tags: c#

```
master page code: 
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Upi" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
          <p  class="text1" id="lbl_cart" runat="server"></p>
     </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>  



client Page code:
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Upi" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1"  runat="server" ImageUrl="images/add-button.png" OnClientClick="getcountr(this)"/>
     </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

how can update the msater control value on click imagebutton1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define click event of Imagebutton like following

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
  var c=  this.Master.FindControl("lbl_cart") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl;      
  c.InnerText = "12122112";
}
```

This way you can modify text of you p tag which is in master page.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your client page:

```
<script language="javascript">
function getcountr(obj) {
    var t = document.getElementById('<%=Master.FindControl("lbl_cart").ClientID %>');
    if (parseFloat(t.innerHTML) > 0) {
        t.innerHTML = parseFloat(t.innerHTML) + 1;
    }
    else {
        t.innerHTML = 1;
    }
}
</script>
```

and in master page:

```
  <p  class="text1" id="lbl_cart" runat="server">0</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find and Update any of the control in a child page that is inherited from master page like that:

## ContentPlaceHolder cp = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("your site.master`s  ContentPlaceHolder Name");

Just write following code in side your 'ImageButton1' click event:

```
private void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ContentPlaceHolder cp = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
        UpdatePanel up1 = cp.FindControl("Upi") as UpdatePanel ;
        up1.Visible= true;//Write your logic here.

    }
```